# application_python failing to install gunicorn on first deploy

Tags: django, vagrant, gunicorn, chef-solo

I've been trying to use https://github.com/poise/application_python/blob/master/examples/recipes-packaginator.rb
in vagrant but for some reason the first deploy always fails with something like

```
Chef::Exceptions::EnclosingDirectoryDoesNotExist: directory[/srv/packaginator/shared/env] (/tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/python/providers/virtualenv.rb line 31) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::EnclosingDirectoryDoesNotExist: Parent directory /srv/packaginator/shared does not exist, cannot create /srv/packaginator/shared/env
```

However if I comment out the part with gunicorn in the recipe

```
gunicorn do
    app_module :django
    port 8080
end
```

the deploy is successful. If I enable it afterwards and re-run the deploy, it succesfully run and creates the gunicorn and supervisor related files.

The recipe seems to be running things out of order.I am using the latest version of Vagrant and Chef 10.14.2 using the precise32.box

application_python is version 2.0.4 (the latest version compatible with chef 10)

EDIT: Even after upgrading to Chef 11.8 (using vagrant-omnibus) the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

"Your recipe code should create needed directories."

@coderanger: https://github.com/poise/python/issues/86